# how to set a fieldLabel color in sencha ex js 7 to color white in items as a displayfield

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, styling

How to set a field label color in **Sencha Ext JS 7** to `color:"white"` in items as a display field

```js
{
  fieldLabel: "Inizio",
  itemId: "dataId",
  xtype: "displayfield",
  labelAlign: "left",
  format: "d-m-Y",
  fieldStyle: { color: "white", position: "relative", right: "58px" },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `labelStyle` config of the field to format the label, [see documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#cfg-labelStyle). It accepts a CSS style so use it like:

```
{
  fieldLabel: 'Inizio',
  labelStyle: 'color: white;',
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  fieldLabel: "Inizio",
  itemId: "dataId",
  xtype: "displayfield",
  labelAlign: "left",
  format: "d-m-Y",
  cls:'inizio-cls' // add class
};
```

**In CSS or SCSS file add class
// Add any css changes you wish to for the field**

```
.inizio-cls {
    color: white;
    background: white;
    position: "relative";
    right: "58px"
}
```